# Repeated measures variance analysis in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a variance test in R that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(hormone = c(65.1, 32.8, 29.6, 42.3),
                 medication = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 lab = c('One', 'Two', 'One', 'Two'))
var.test(hormone ~ medication, data = df)
```

I want to control this variance tests for the fact that several tests are done in the same `lab`. Essentially if I were doing an ANOVA, it would look like this:

```
aov(hormone ~ medication + Error(lab), data = df)
```

which is a repeated measures ANOVA. I tried putting `+ Error(lab)` into `var.test`, but that throws an error. How do I do this?